# Android Emulator becomes very slow all of a sudden

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am using the Android version 4.0.3 on a Windows system. My emulator was working pretty well, however all of sudden it became very slow.

It is taking too much time in launching so most of the time launch gets cancelled or I have to start the emulator ahead of time.

Comment: ... just use a GNU/linux distribution, it's the natural environment for Android and it's not junky.

Comment: You don't need to exit the emulator each time you run your app. Emulator window can stay open.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am not exiting everytime. However launching the new one is taking too much time which was not the earlier case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are having long times in emulator startup, you can configure AVD to save a snapshot of emulator. This significantly improves startup time, although the shutdown time will increase due to the saving of snapshot.

If you are having a slow emulator in general (booting and running programs), and, if you are using a Intel x86 processor you can install `Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager` from android SDK. This will improve emulator speed by more then 10 times compared to the standard emulator. It even faster then a mid range real device.

good luck.

Comment: the HAXM also works on AMD cpus, also it's not for all the Intel cpus but only the one with VT related technologies.

Answer (score 0):

The emulators, all of them, on every platform, are infamous for slow startups. Typically you start the emulator, wait 'til it is all the way up, and then run your program. Debugging on a real device is infinitely preferable.

Leaving the emulator open between program runs is a necessity.

One of my professors gave up and spent several thousand dollars on a new computer with a huge solid-state drive because he could not get an emulator window up in less than five minutes, and it was impacting his ability to teach courses based on the platform. I went the cheaper route and dropped $200 on a tablet. Either way, hardware is the real answer here.